# How to resolve Call to undefined function idn_to_ascii() error in php 7.3.8?

Tags: php

I installed `WampServer` and it has this mechanism to create virtualhosts from graphic user interface. It worked the first time around but after I updated the php version to 7.3.8 today, it starts showing the error mentioned in the question. I have enabled the intl extension already but to no avail.

So where does this function referenced to anyway? How to resolve this issue?

Tried enabling intl extension.

> Line 347 of www\add_vhost.php file is causing problem: $vh_nameIDN =
>   idn_to_ascii($vh_name,IDNA_DEFAULT,INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46);

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php - it must be explicitly enabled at installation time

Comment: Well I just changed php version to 7.3.8 in wampserver and that broke it. Before that, it worked. Is there anything I have to do other than that?

Answer (score 3):

OK, so I got it working doing this:

1. Copy all the files with icu*.dll naming in your php version folder [C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.8 -> in my case]
2. Paste those files in "apache/your_apache_version/".[C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.39\bin -> in my case]
3. Restart the services.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

I went to `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.0.12` <- [my PHP version] and copied the following files:

```
icudt68.dll
icuin68.dll
icuio68.dll
icuuc68.dll
```

And I pasted it into `C: \ wamp64 \ bin \ apache \ apache2.4.46 \ bin` <- [my version of Apache].

With that, it worked immediately.

Note: The 4 files listed above must remain in your PHP version folder. In that case, there will be only one copy of the four files above.